# In PHP how do I hide unanswered fields?

Tags: php

I am creating a very long form and not all fields will be answered, how can I hide unanswered fields after they hit the send button and I receive the email?

So what I'm wondering is what can I add to my script to hide a blank field after the submit button is sent.

```
 /* Data Variables */

$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$uplift = $_POST['uplift'];
$upliftc = $_POST['upliftc'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
$deliveryc = $_POST['deliveryc'];
$city2 = $_POST['city2'];
$post2 = $_POST['post2'];
$ground = $_POST['ground'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$second2 = $_POST['second2'];
$ground2 = $_POST['ground2'];
$internal =$_POST['internal'];
$internal2 =$_POST['internal2'];
$external =$_POST['external'];
$external2 =$_POST['external2'];
$access =$_POST['access'];
$queen = $_POST['queen'] * 1.7;





$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Phone; $phone <br>
<br>
Uplift; $uplift <br>
Continued; $upliftc <br>
City; $city <br>
Post Code; $post <br>
<br>
Delivery Address; $delivery <br>
Continued; $deliveryc <br>
City; $city2 <br>
Post; $post2 <br>
<br>
Uplift; <br>
Ground Floor; $ground <br>
Second Floor; $second <br>
Internal Stairs; $internal <br>
External Stairs; $external <br>
<br>
Delivery; <br>
Ground Floor; $ground2 <br>
Second Floor; $second2 <br>
Internal Stairs; $internal2 <br>
External Stairs; $external2 <br>
Truck Access; $access <br>
Queen Bed; $queen <br>
```

Comment: Use a loop to populate the output (with a input variable name to title array map) instead of a HEREDOC blob.

Comment: First of all you will need to move out of the `heredoc` string formation and provide tests for each field testing if its empty or not and concatenate with the final string

Comment: Use an `if(!isset...` type of thing or `if(empty...`.

Comment: Consult the PHP manual on `if(empty)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php **and** on `if(isset)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php - am sure these will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have mentioned the `isset()` function, but that won't work.  Even if the user does not fill in the value when submitting the form, the variable is still set, so all variables will return `TRUE` when run through `isset()`.  `empty()` is your best bet.

You can use a loop to both test the values and to populate the email body, but it will require a slight re-design of your HTML form by giving the values different names, for instance, instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="email">
```

Use:

```
<input type="text" name="field[Email]">
```

This will create `$_POST['field']` as an array with values such as `$_POST['field']['email']` that will include your values.  Technically, you could do this without renaming the fields and looping through `$_POST` itself, but this would assume that you are not posting any non-field-related data, and that you never will.. not a safe assumption.

Once you have your HTML form fields renamed, the PHP code to process the request would look like this:

```
$email_body = "";
if( is_array( $_POST['field'] )) {
    foreach( $_POST['field'] as $name => $value ) {
        if( !empty( $value )) {
            $email_body .= "$name: $value<br>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

That's a lot less code than what you have written.  It will also omit blank values and will support adding new fields by only modifying the HTML form without having to modify the PHP code that processes it.

I do notice that the email body that you're generating seems to break the values into sections.  You can do that using the same idea as what I've written above by adding another index to the array, and it'll maintain dynamic nature of creating the HTML form fields, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="field[Contact][Email]">
```

And then for the PHP:

```
$email_body = "";
if( is_array( $_POST['field'] )) {
    foreach( $_POST['field'] as $category => $fields ) {
        $email_body .= "<br>\n";

        if( is_array( $fields )) {
            foreach( $fields as $name => $value ) {
                if( !empty( $value )) {
                    $email_body .= "$name: $value<br>\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, this is my first script and it will take me some time to work it all out, but im getting there. I had just been linking the php to the html and not doing any code in html, but it looks like i will have to learn both at the same time if i want things done the right way.

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with the way you're doing it, it'll just be a lot more lines of code to do it that way, and you'll have to maintain two separate pieces (both the PHP and the HTML form) if you go that static route.

Comment: I'm going to start from scratch and see how i go, i like what you have suggested and im going to run with it. Cheers

Comment: Wonderful! Maybe you can accept an answer to your question then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

As in not request it if it wasn't filled in?

```
if(!isset($_POST['access'])){
// Do whatever
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `isset($variable_name)` function that returns true if given variable has value, and false otherwise.